# JUnit HTML report (index.html) is not generated in the JUNIT folder, If I run the test case through ANT in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, selenium-webdriver, junit

I am running the JUnit test cases through ANT in eclipse, the build is successful, however the JUnit Html report of the test cases (index.html) is not generated in the JUnit folder.

Following are the versions:

ANT: apache-ant-1.9.4
JUnit: junit 4.11 Jar file
Eclipse: Version: 3.7.2

Please help!

Comment: Please edit your question and add your Ant script with `<junit>` in it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using ant junit task for running testcases. However, to generate HTML report, you need to add junit report task. Please, see example above

```
<target name="test-html">
  <junit fork="yes" printsummary="no" haltonfailure="no">
    <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${test.reports}" >
      <fileset dir="${classes}">
        <include name="**/*Test.class" />
      </fileset>
    </batchtest>
    <formatter type="xml" />
    <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
  </junit>

  <junitreport todir="${test.reports}">
    <fileset dir="${test.reports}">
      <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
    </fileset>
    <report todir="${test.reports}" />
  </junitreport>
</target>
```